# Swift Crash in getter for location services

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, getter

I received several crashes in Xcode organizer, but I'm not able to find the root cause for it. Would be nice, if someone could look at it and give his thoughts ...

[image: Crash shown in Xcode Organizer]

... here is the code of the getter

```
// most recent location received
var _mostRecentLocationReceived : CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
var mostRecentLocationReceived : CLLocation {
    set (newValue) {
        _mostRecentLocationReceived = newValue
    }
    
    get {
        // check if someone already set the variable
        if ((_mostRecentLocationReceived.coordinate.latitude != 0.0)
            && (_mostRecentLocationReceived.coordinate.longitude != 0.0))
        {
            // yes, so return it
            return _mostRecentLocationReceived
            
        } else {
            
            // not set so far, provide a helper value
            
            // first atempt, the current location from location manager
            if WTS.unique.WTS_LocationManager != nil {
                if WTS.unique.WTS_LocationManager!.location != nil {
                    return WTS.unique.WTS_LocationManager!.location!
                }
            }
            
            // second atempt the last stored center of the map
            return CLLocation(latitude: WaysMapOnScreenLastCenter.latitude,
                              longitude: WaysMapOnScreenLastCenter.longitude)
        }
    }
}
```

Crash marked this lines as reason

```
if ((_mostRecentLocationReceived.coordinate.latitude != 0.0)
            && (_mostRecentLocationReceived.coordinate.longitude != 0.0))
```

.. any idea is welcomed!!

Hardy

Comment: Could it be that you're accessing this property on two different threads?

Comment: Why not make `_mostRecentLocationReceived` optional and default it to `nil` instead of using a special value?

Comment: to matt, will check, but I don't think so

Comment: To HangarRash ... right, good idea .. will rework and test

Comment: to matt, yes, it is called on main and on other places from a worker thread ... but I think this should be no problem, or am I wrong?

Comment: to HangarRash well, global variables need initialized values, that's why  `_mostRecentLocationReceived` is predefined with `CLLocation(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)`

Comment: @Hardy_Germany It’s not a global. It’s a property. Use `var _mostRecentLocationReceived : CLLocation? = nil`

Comment: @HangarRash, yes you are right, I was mislead by the compiler message, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final fix, using the answers of `HangarRash` and `matt`

AND yes! The crashes are gone ;-)

```
// queue to handle the getter and setter of _mostRecentLocationReceivedQueue
let _mostRecentLocationReceivedQueue : DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(
    label: "org.hobrink.WayAndSee.mostRecentLocationReceivedQueue",
    qos: .default, attributes: .concurrent)

var _mostRecentLocationReceived : CLLocation? = nil
var mostRecentLocationReceived : CLLocation {
    set (newValue) {
        _mostRecentLocationReceivedQueue.async (flags: .barrier, execute: {
            _mostRecentLocationReceived = newValue
        })
    }
    
    get {
        return _mostRecentLocationReceivedQueue.sync {
            
            // check if someone already set the variable
            if (_mostRecentLocationReceived != nil) {
                
                // yes, so return it
                return _mostRecentLocationReceived!
                
            } else {
                
                // not set so far, provide a helper value
                
                // first atempt, the current location from location manager
                if WTS.unique.WTS_LocationManager != nil {
                    if WTS.unique.WTS_LocationManager!.location != nil {
                        return WTS.unique.WTS_LocationManager!.location!
                    }
                }
                
                // second atempt the last stored center of the map
                return CLLocation(latitude: WaysMapOnScreenLastCenter.latitude,
                                  longitude: WaysMapOnScreenLastCenter.longitude)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would change the `if (_mostRecentLocationReceived != nil) {` to use better optional unwrapping: `if let _mostRecentLocationReceived { return _mostRecentLocationReceived } else { ...`.

Comment: Yes, I think it's some kind of personnel coding style. For me it's easier to read this way .. and the optimizer will generate the same code  ;-)